# Why is my router-link tag not working with my bootstrap framework?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using vue.js to create a navigation task bar along with bootstrap for the frontend framework.

I configured the router in a router.js file I created.

#### router.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)
    
//enter code here`import components     
import levi from './containers/levi'
import product from './containers/product'
import price from './containers/price'


//application routes 

const routes = [
  {path: '/', component: levi },
  {path: '/product', component: product },
  {path:'/price', component: price }
]


//export router instance 

export default new Router({     
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
  linkActiveClass:'is-active'
})
```

I created the containers with the files for the navigation bar.

#### price.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id = "price" >
    What is the price!  
  </div>
</template>

<script>  
export default{
    name: 'price'  
}
</script>


<style scoped>

</style>
```

#### product.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id = "product">   
      Understanding the levi product
  </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
       name: 'product'   
   }
</script>

<style scoped>
   
</style>
```

The components folder has the navigation component

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container ">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">levi</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" name="button">
          <span class="navbar-toggle-Menu">Menu</span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This div section contains the router-link tags that are not working properly

```html
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <router-link to='/product'> product </router-link>
</div>
```

end tag for the router-link

```html
<template></template>

<script>
  export default {
     name : 'navigation'
  }
</script>
    
<style scoped = "true">

</style>
```

All the initial navigation links are no longer showing when I surround them with the router-link. How can I fix this?

Comment: wich version of vue are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the instance of your router to your main Vue instance like so:

```js
//your router is declared as default in its own file so
//in your main Vue instance...

import router from './my_router'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router
})
```